# Error using replaceSubrange with Array of Doubles: SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, observableobject

```
import Foundation
import CoreData
import SwiftUI

struct dailyModel: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID =  UUID()
    let amount: Double
}


class DailyListModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var dailys: [dailyModel] = []
    
    init() {
        getItems()
    }
    
    func getItems() {
        let newDailys = [
            dailyModel(amount: 0.0),
        ]
        dailys.append(contentsOf: newDailys)
    }

    func addItems(amount: Double) {
        let newItem = dailyModel(amount: amount)
        dailys.replaceSubrange(1, with: newItem)
    }
}
```

I get an error on line 'daily.replacesubrange' with red line under the first 'd' that says "*Instance method 'replaceSubrange(_:with:)' requires that 'dailyModel' conform to 'Collection'*"

Should I change dailyModel to also include Collection or change how I am using replaceSubrange?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are **two** issues:

1. *requires that 'dailyModel' conform to 'Collection'* means that the `with` parameter must be a collection like

   ```
   with: [newItem]
   ```
2. The first parameter must be a range (`Range<Int>`), not a single `Int`, for a single item you can write

   ```
   replaceSubrange(1...1,
   ```

If you replace only one item you could also write

```
func addItem(amount: Double) {
    let newItem = dailyModel(amount: amount)
    dailys.remove(at: 1)
    dailys.insert(newItem, at: 1)
}
```